# How to convert byte array to BigInteger in java

Tags: java

I'm working on java... I want to know how to convert array of byte into BigInteger.
     Actually i used md5's digest method which returned me array of byte which i want to convert into Biginteger.

Comment: @Stephen C :) :) , I meant in which manner particularly, It can be simple array of byte[] also String content's byte representation

Answer (score 8):

This example [Get MD5 hash in a few lines of Java](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/3686) has a related example.

I believe you should be able to do

```
MessageDigest m=MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
m.update(message.getBytes(), 0, message.length());
BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1,m.digest());
```

and if you want it printed in the style `"d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e"` you should be able to do

```
System.out.println(bi.toString(16));
```

Answer (score 5):

> Actually i used md5's digest method which returned me array of byte which i want to convert into a `BigInteger`.

You can use `new BigInteger(byte[])`.

However, it should be noted that the MD5 hash is not really an integer in any useful sense.  It is really just a binary bit pattern.

I guess you are just doing this so that you can print or order the MD5 hashes.  But there are less memory hungry ways of accomplishing both tasks.

Comment: better to use the integer,byte[] constructor. this one will interpret it as a two's complement binary representation